# Configuring Sentry with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, sentry, raven

I am trying to integrate Sentry error reporting with my react app. I have it working with my backend fine, but I am now having issues with the frontend.

What I have found is that if I run the Raven.configure("sdn").install() from my webrowser console, the error logging will work.

I have added the the script & configure to my index.html, but it will not log errors without my manually configuring in the browser console.

Thanks

Comment: Updated to react 16+ now works exactly as defined in the sentry docs without any issue.